# Activate a AWS Data Pipeline Multiple Times From an AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-data-pipeline, aws-lambda

Can anyone explain how to activate an AWS Data Pipeline multiple times with a source parameter via an AWS Lambda execution.

Currently the first processing activates the pipeline but then any subsequent activation's fail with or without a message (depending on the activation parameters)

The full processing loop is to move data to S3 then to initiate a DataPipeline to migrate data to Redshift.

```
    Example 1: aws datapipeline activate-pipeline --pipeline-id {pipelineid}
    Accepts command but will not execute on previously run pipeline


    Example 2: aws datapipeline activate-pipeline --pipeline-id {pipelineid} --end-timestamp, 2015-07-08T00:00:00Z 
    Error: Unknown options: --end-timestamp, 2015-07-08T00:00:00Z 


  Example 3: aws datapipeline activate-pipeline --pipeline-id {pipelineid} --start-timestamp, 2015-07-08T00:00:00Z     
A client error (InvalidRequestException) occured when calling the ActivatePipeline operation: startTimestamp shoudl not be later than any Schedule EndDateTime in the pipeline)
```

This excerpt was taken from AWS Documentation:

> To activate a finished pipeline, modify the end date for the pipeline
>   and then activate it.

[AWS Documentation Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/datapipeline/activate-pipeline.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aws datapipeline activate-pipeline --pipeline-id {pipelineid} --start-timestamp 2015-10-15T14:15:18Z
```

- `{pipelineid}` is your *df-xxxxx*.
- `2015-10-15T14:15:18Z` is the time when started first time to run the pipeline. (just an example)

We use in prod this way and works perfect, we can run any finished datapipelines.

Comment: On specifying the startTimestamp its returns "**startTimestamp should not be later than any Schedule EndDateTime in the pipeline**"! Any help?How to edit the EndDateTime?

Comment: check Schedule interval and just include starting not ending( any activity wen started should have same start time)                                                  for example: **2016-02-02 15:02:36 - 2016-02-03 15:02:36** you would use **2016-02-02T15:02:36** and should work.–

Answer (score 0):

Your pipeline definition should have an endTime defined on the schedule. You'll need to edit the definition to change that to be after the startDateTime.

--end-timestamp is not an valid parameter